# Hadoop access HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed hadoop and I can't use -copyFromLocal , it responses

```
[root@hadoop-master ~]# hadoop fs -copyFromLocal file.dat 
copyFromLocal: `.': No such file or directory
```

I have tryed -mkdir dir but it responses

```
[root@hadoop-master ~]# hadoop fs -mkdir dir
mkdir: `dir': No such file or directory
```

and -ls

```
[root@hadoop-master ~]# hadoop fs -ls
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

Only it works when I change my user

```
su hdfs
hadoop fs -mkdir tfm
```

but it fails when I try again -copyFromLocal

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS is the Owner of the Hadoop file system so you are able to create directories using HDFS user refer bellow mention commands to create directory or to copy files

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /path/dir
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal localpath hdfspath
```

or make sure the user (from whom your are running the command) have needed permissions on the directory you are running the command.

Comment: could you please tell me how to navigate in directories

Comment: @Francy use the browser which is generally namenodeIP:50070 to visualize the directory and also you can use use ls command as hadoop fs -ls /path/dir

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
hadoop fs -ls /
hadoop fs -lsr /
hadoop fs -mkdir /dir
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal localfilename /newlocation
```